# Settings of Bespin embedded?

Tags: javascript, bespin

I guess most of you know the web-based code editor - [Mozilla's Bespin project](https://bespin.mozilla.com/).

Two weeks ago they [published their first release](http://mozillalabs.com/bespin/2009/11/13/bespin-embedded-first-preview-release/) of an embedded version:

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20091121-xuamnt5ribje25fp666ixyd67k.png](http://img.skitch.com/20091121-xuamnt5ribje25fp666ixyd67k.png)

Being in a alpha stage the [documentation](https://bespin.mozilla.com/docs/) isn't really satisfying.

Although there is list of [settings](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Bespin/Settings) I wasn't able to change the syntax to js.
How do you achieve this?

There is a bespin.setSetting method but I have no clue how to use it.

Only one [sample code](http://hg.mozilla.org/labs/bespin/file/43ecc1001d47/frontend/tests/editor/singleeditor.html) ( the one shown on the screen shot above ) uses js syntax highlighting.
But it also uses Dojo and I would like to avoid using Dojo.

Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bespin seems to use some dojo commands somehow.
However it does not require the dojo libraries.

JS (onload):

```
new bespin.editor.Component("editor", {
    language: "js",
    loadfromdiv: true
});
```

HTML (head):

```
<script src="https://bespin.mozilla.com/embed.js"></script>
```

HTML (body):

```
<div id="editor"></div>
```

---

Result: [JS highlighted editor](http://jsbin.com/uzeyi)