# How to add a simple 'save' button to bespin editor?

Tags: bespin

Followed the simple tutorial from here

[Settings of Bespin embedded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774776/settings-of-bespin-embedded)

But cannot figure a way to add a 'save' button that would trigger an ajax event or whatever so i can process it and save the content to a file.

Any clues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'd want to to go here is get a handle to the text value of the editor in javascript and post that server side to save either as a file or in a db.

You can get the editor text value this way:

```
var editor = env.editor;
var value = editor.value;
```

One easy trick would be to copy that value to a hidden field so you could process it like you might any other form field.